# ControlsFX Throws an Exception Upon Showing?

Tags: java, maven, controlsfx

This program doesn't work: `Platform.runLater(() -> Notifications.create().text("Hello!").showError());`

If throws a null-pointer when invoked.
Exception:

> `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.controlsfx.control.Notifications$NotificationPopupHandler.show(Notifications.java:334)
>       at org.controlsfx.control.Notifications$NotificationPopupHandler.show(Notifications.java:322)
>       at org.controlsfx.control.Notifications.show(Notifications.java:269)
>       at org.controlsfx.control.Notifications.showError(Notifications.java:253)`

I get the distinct feeling that this is somehow maven related, as I use controlsfx all the time, but this is the first time I'm using it in a maven environment.

POM:

> ```
> <dependencies>
>     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
>         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
>         <version>2.6</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
>         <version>2.9.5</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>4.12</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
>         <version>1.3</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
>         <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
>         <version>8.40.14</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

```
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.opusconverter.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>jackofall</shadedClassifierName> <!-- Any name that makes sense -->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```